# how to call a webapi from javascript if the 2 functions has same arguments types

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2013

I'm newbie with WebAPI and try to learn by googeling and searching.

I'm able to accomplish a CRUD which works fine with API. I'm calling this WebAPI from Javascript which works fine.

But I've this situation.

Embplyee     and   EmployeeTime

Employee contains: ID, Username, Name
EmployeeTime contains: ID, DateIn, Employee_Id

with EmployeeController I can do update/delete/Add   -> I'm using the ID.

now with EmployeeTimeController -> I can also do update/Add/Delete.
But how can I do a CRUD operation on EmployeeTimeController, by "Employee_Id"?

```
 public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetEmployeeTime(int id)
    {
        TimeAttendance timeattendance = await db.TimeAttendances.FindAsync(id);
        if (timeattendance == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(timeattendance);
    }
```

As you can see the id in argument is linked with Id of EmployeeTime.Id.

I like to get the all records from by passing the Employee.Employee_Id

```
 public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetEmployeeTimeByEmployee(int employeeId)
    {
        TimeAttendance timeattendance = dbContext.EmployeeTime.Where(e=> e.Employee_Id == employeeId).ToList<timeattendance>();
        if (timeattendance == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(timeattendance);
    }
```

So in short:
when I call from javascript :

```
//it returns employee with employee.ID 2
http://localhost:24374/api/employees/2

//it returns employeeTime RECORD with employeeTime.ID 4
http://localhost:24374/api/employeesTime/4

//How do I get all records from employeeTime which employee_Id = 4
http://localhost:24374/api/employeesTime/??????
```

I like to pass the Employee_Id value in to "EmployeeTimeController", but since both have the same argument type (INT), how can I make the distingue?

I can create a new function with different name in Controller, but how to call from javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put a method in the employee controller called GetEmployeeTime and you can configure it with a route attribute:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/employees/{id}/Time")]
public YourModel GetEmployeeTime(int id){
   Your code here
}
```

You can then call it via JS using the url:

```
http://localhost:24374/api/employees/2/Time
```

Comment: thanks so much and for your quick response Magrangs,  I tested it works fine. So I just need to add the [route] there (with httpGet).